# In the ToDo app when click on a date, I get a list of duplicate of task. How to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, redux

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-cloud-0fucl?file=/src/components/todo-list/todo-list.jsx

Ccomponent TodoList return TodoListMonth (in folder '/todo-list-item/todo-list-month') component if ModalMain true else return TodoListDaily (in folder '/todo-list-item/todo-list-day')

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at your `TodoListDaily` component:

```
const TodoListDaily = ({
  selectedDate,
  todoData,
  deleteTask,
  setDone,
  modalDetails,
  toggleModalDetails
}) => {
  const existTask = todoData.filter(item => item.date === selectedDate);

  const elements = todoData.map(item => {
    const { id, ...itemProps } = item;

    // ...

    return (
      <li key={id} className="list-group-item">
        {existTask.map(({ id, done, topic, date, month }) => {
          return (
            <div className="todo-list-item-label">
              {/*  ... */}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="todo-list-wrap">
      <h1 className="title-card">{selectedDate + `th May`}</h1>
      <ul className="list-group todo-list">{elements}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

First you filter `todoData`, but then you iterate over your unfiltered data! So lets change it to `const elements = existTask.map(item => {`. But then inside your map function, you iterate again over your filtered data, `existTask`. So if you had two items on the same date, four list entries would be rendered. You can probably just remove the second `map`, so we get:

```
const TodoListDaily = ({
  selectedDate,
  todoData,
  deleteTask,
  setDone,
  modalDetails,
  toggleModalDetails
}) => {
  const existTask = todoData.filter(item => item.date === selectedDate);

  const elements = existTask.map(item => {
    const { id, done, topic, date, month } = item;

    // ...

    return (
      <li key={id} className="list-group-item">
        <div className="todo-list-item-label">
          {/*  ... */}
        </div>
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div className="todo-list-wrap">
      <h1 className="title-card">{selectedDate + `th May`}</h1>
      <ul className="list-group todo-list">{elements}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I would also recommend to extract the `map` callback into its own component. Anytime JSX is returned from a function, it's probably a good candidate for its own component.

For example, a trimmed down version of `TodoListDaily` could look like this:

```
const TodoListDaily = ({ selectedDate, todoData }) => {
  return (
    <div className="todo-list-wrap">
      <h1 className="title-card">{selectedDate + `th May`}</h1>
      <ul className="list-group todo-list">
        {todoData
          .filter(item => item.date === selectedDate)
          .map(item => {
            return <ListItem key={item.id} {...item} />;
          })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This makes it arguably easier to understand by having smaller components with fewer dependencies. But it also makes it work better with React. For example, more granular React components avoid unnecessary rerendering and help with the React Dev Tools as you can see the props passed to each list entry.

You can find the sandbox I used for debugging here (including an extracted list item component): https://codesandbox.io/s/todo-app-k6i6l